# How to write correct Pytest test for my code?

Tags: python, unit-testing, oop, object, pytest

I want to create 2 tests for handleEmail():
1. Email is ok, don't have any error
2. That function throws message Email is either wrong format or duplicate

However, I don't know how to do that because it doesn't return anything. So how to test this function ?

```
class RegisterController:    
    def handleEmail(self):
        """get email from user, check email then display message
        """
        self.getEmail()
        status = self.model.checkEmailOk(self.email)
        if not status:
            message = "Email is either wrong format or duplicate"
            self.displaymessage(message)
            return self.handleEmail()

     def createAccount(self):
        self.handleEmail()
        self.handlePasswordValid()
```

Comment: And why is handleEmail() calling itself recursively?

Comment: @Francky_V, if email is not ok, it will require email again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

- separately test how `checkEmailOk()` function checks an email and what status does it return for which email
- using mock and/or [`pytest-mock`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock):

  - mock `checkEmailOk()` and return a truthy or falsy value
  - mock `displaymessage()` function to check whether it was called or not and check what argument it was called with if called (e.g. using `assert_called_once_with()` assertion method if you are gonna be using `pytest-mock`)

In general, though, it is a really good thing you are adding tests, as **you are actually using your code when you are writing tests for it**. Just notice how easy and straightforward it is to add tests for your code, and, if you see problems/complications in checking certain use cases, reaching certain pre-conditions/behavior when adding tests, that could be a sign of poor design and usability of your code under test and a *good reason* to think of re-factoring/re-structuring it.

Answer (score 0):

Your method could return the status (should?). Then you could just assert that the status returned in good for a valid email.

For the other part -raising an exception:

```
import unittest
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_sample(self):
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            c = "a" + 42
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

With self.assertRaises(...), you can tell your test you're going to do something that SHOULD raise an error. The test passes if an Exception is raised (counter-intuitive but makes sense to test that). So above adding a string with an int is a TypeError, because there's not definition of addition for a string with an int in python. Therefore that line raises a TypeError exception. The test case sees the exception, and since I told it it would happen, the test passes.

You should then in your code raise an Exception, let's say:

```
if not status:
    raise Exception(" Wrong email ")
```

Ideally not raise a generic exception like that - you would probably want to create a custom exception (or maybe I'M getting too far here, if you don't know/want to get fancy a generic exception is fine).